# Why does my container keep building the same layer?

Tags: node.js, docker

The container below is currently failing at after the second run. In trying to debug it, I have to run it again.

```
FROM node:10-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy app
COPY . .

# USER root 
# install packages
RUN apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
   git \ 
   python \ 
   make \ 
   g++ \ 
   && npm config set user 0 \
   && npm config set unsafe-perm true \
   && npm i -g wait-on concurrently  truffle@4.1.15\
   && npm install \
   && apk del build-dependencies

RUN truffle compile --all // FAILS HERE

# Expose the right ports, the commands below are irrelevant when using a docker-compose file.
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "server"]
```

Whenever I rebuild the container, it starts overs from the first RUN which makes the process longer.

My understanding of docker is that layers in containers  should be cached and only rebuilt if a file changes?

I would appreciate pointers on this.

Comment: Take a look at multi stage builds, they might help you here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instruction in a Dockerfile results in an image layer (with a few exceptions), and image layers are used as a cache during builds. But, as soon as one layer is invalidated, all subsequent layers have to be rebuilt.

In your example, if the `COPY . .` instruction results in a difference, then the following `RUN apk ...` instruction will also be invalidated, causing it to be re-run.

I suggest installing the Alpine packages before you copy in your project files, and then doing the npm install after.

Answer (score 1):

Are you changing the docker file while debugging or any another file in your current directory where your docker file is present? If yes, then `COPY . .`, is basically copying your docker file or app files also inside the docker image and since files are changed with every build, all layers below this including `COPY . .`  will not be used from cache. So only `WORKDIR /usr/src/app` will be used from cache.

Hope this helps.